# How to set the text value of Multiline text field in sharepoint using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Using below code to set the field value in sharepoint using c#

```
using (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite site = new Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://soweto:5000/sites/SPDWF_Issue"))
            {
                using (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList list = web.Lists["Cust"];

                    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();                    

                    SPFieldMultiLineText actionField =
                        item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Action")
                            as SPFieldMultiLineText;
                    item["Action"] = actionField.GetFieldValueAsText("<Action ActionType=\"Metalogix.SharePoint.Actions.Migration.PasteListAction, Metalogix.SharePoint.Actions, Version=8.3.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3b240fac3e39fc03\"><CopyListPermissions Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</CopyListPermissions><FilterLists Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</FilterLists><ListFilterExpression Type=\"Metalogix.Data.Filters.IFilterExpression\"><And IsImplicitGroup=\"True\" /></ListFilterExpression><OverwriteLists Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</OverwriteLists><UpdateLists Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</UpdateLists><OverwriteFolders Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</OverwriteFolders><UpdateListOptionsBitField Type=\"System.Int32\">0</UpdateListOptionsBitField><CheckModifiedDatesForLists Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</CheckModifiedDatesForLists><CopyCustomizedFormPages Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</CopyCustomizedFormPages><CopyListOOBWorkflowAssociations Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</CopyListOOBWorkflowAssociations><CopyWebOOBWorkflowAssociations Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</CopyWebOOBWorkflowAssociations><CopyContentTypeOOBWorkflowAssociations Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</CopyContentTypeOOBWorkflowAssociations><CopyListSharePointDesignerNintexWorkflowAssociations Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</CopyListSharePointDesignerNintexWorkflowAssociations><CopyWebSharePointDesignerNintexWorkflowAssociations Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</CopyWebSharePointDesignerNintexWorkflowAssociations><CopyContentTypeSharePointDesignerNintexWorkflowAssociations Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</CopyContentTypeSharePointDesignerNintexWorkflowAssociations><CopyNintexDatabaseEntries Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</CopyNintexDatabaseEntries><CopyPreviousVersionOfWorkflowInstances Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</CopyPreviousVersionOfWorkflowInstances><CopyGloballyReusableWorkflowTemplates Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</CopyGloballyReusableWorkflowTemplates><CopyViewWebParts Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</CopyViewWebParts><CopyFormWebParts Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</CopyFormWebParts><FilterFolders Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</FilterFolders><FolderFilterExpression Type=\"Metalogix.Data.Filters.IFilterExpression\"><And IsImplicitGroup=\"True\" /></FolderFilterExpression><CopyFolderPermissions Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</CopyFolderPermissions><UpdateFolderOptionsBitField Type=\"System.Int32\">0</UpdateFolderOptionsBitField><CopyListItems Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</CopyListItems><UseAzureOffice365Upload Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</UseAzureOffice365Upload><EncryptAzureMigrationJobs Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</EncryptAzureMigrationJobs><CopyDocumentWebParts Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</CopyDocumentWebParts><CopyClosedWebParts Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</CopyClosedWebParts><CopyContentZoneContent Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</CopyContentZoneContent><ExistingWebPartsAction Type=\"Metalogix.SharePoint.Options.Migration.ExistingWebPartsProtocol\">Delete</ExistingWebPartsAction><CopyWebPartsAtItemsLevel Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</CopyWebPartsAtItemsLevel><CopyDefaultPageWebPartsAtItemsLevel Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</CopyDefaultPageWebPartsAtItemsLevel><FilterItems Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</FilterItems><FilterFields Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</FilterFields><ItemFilterExpression Type=\"Metalogix.Data.Filters.IFilterExpression\" /><ListFieldsFilterExpression Type=\"Metalogix.Data.Filters.IFilterExpression\"><And IsImplicitGroup=\"True\" /></ListFieldsFilterExpression><RenameSpecificNodes Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</RenameSpecificNodes><TaskCollection Type=\"Metalogix.DataStructures.TransformationTaskCollection\"><TransformationTaskCollection /></TaskCollection><MapColumns Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</MapColumns><ColumnMappings Type=\"Metalogix.SharePoint.Options.Migration.Mapping.ColumnMappings\"><ColumnMappingsList AutoMapCreatedAndModified=\"False\"><FieldsFilter><And IsImplicitGroup=\"True\" /></FieldsFilter><XmlableSet /></ColumnMappingsList></ColumnMappings><MapTermStores Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</MapTermStores><CopyRootPermissions Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</CopyRootPermissions><MapRolesByName Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</MapRolesByName><ClearRoleAssignments Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</ClearRoleAssignments><OverrideRoleMappings Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</OverrideRoleMappings><RoleAssignmentMappings Type=\"Metalogix.Data.ConditionalMappingCollection\"><XmlableSet /></RoleAssignmentMappings><CopyItemPermissions Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</CopyItemPermissions><ItemCopyingMode Type=\"Metalogix.SharePoint.Options.ListItemCopyMode\">Overwrite</ItemCopyingMode><UpdateItems Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</UpdateItems><CheckModifiedDatesForItemsDocuments Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</CheckModifiedDatesForItemsDocuments><UpdateItemOptionsBitField Type=\"System.Int32\">0</UpdateItemOptionsBitField><PropagateItemDeletions Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</PropagateItemDeletions><ReattachPageLayouts Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</ReattachPageLayouts><CopyVersions Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</CopyVersions><CopySubFolders Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</CopySubFolders><CopyMaxVersions Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</CopyMaxVersions><MaximumVersionCount Type=\"System.Int32\">1</MaximumVersionCount><PreserveItemIDs Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</PreserveItemIDs><PreserveDocumentIDs Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</PreserveDocumentIDs><PreserveSharePointDocumentIDs Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</PreserveSharePointDocumentIDs><ShallowCopyExternalizedData Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</ShallowCopyExternalizedData><DisableDocumentParsing Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</DisableDocumentParsing><ApplyNewContentTypes Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</ApplyNewContentTypes><ContentTypeApplicationObjects Type=\"Metalogix.DataStructures.Generic.CommonSerializableList`1[[Metalogix.SharePoint.Options.Migration.ContentTypeApplicationOptionsCollection, Metalogix.SharePoint.Options, Version=8.3.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3b240fac3e39fc03]]\" /><ApplyNewDocumentSets Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</ApplyNewDocumentSets><DocumentSetApplicationObjects Type=\"Metalogix.DataStructures.Generic.CommonSerializableList`1[[Metalogix.SharePoint.Options.Migration.DocumentSetApplicationOptionsCollection, Metalogix.SharePoint.Options, Version=8.3.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3b240fac3e39fc03]]\" /><FolderToDocumentSetApplicationObjects Type=\"Metalogix.DataStructures.Generic.CommonSerializableList`1[[Metalogix.SharePoint.Options.Migration.DocumentSetFolderOptions, Metalogix.SharePoint.Options, Version=8.3.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3b240fac3e39fc03]]\" /><CopyWorkflowInstanceData Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</CopyWorkflowInstanceData><CopyInProgressWorkflows Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</CopyInProgressWorkflows><ResolveManagedMetadataByName Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</ResolveManagedMetadataByName><CopyReferencedManagedMetadata Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</CopyReferencedManagedMetadata><TermstoreNameMappingTable Type=\"Metalogix.DataStructures.Generic.CommonSerializableTable`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]\"><XmlableTable /></TermstoreNameMappingTable><SideLoadDocuments Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</SideLoadDocuments><MigrationMode Type=\"Metalogix.SharePoint.Options.MigrationMode\">Full</MigrationMode><MapAudiences Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</MapAudiences><Verbose Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</Verbose><LogSkippedItems Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</LogSkippedItems><CheckResults Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</CheckResults><CompareOptions Type=\"Metalogix.DataStructures.ComparisonOptions\"><ComparisonOptions ComparisonLevel=\"Moderate\" /></CompareOptions><ForceRefresh Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</ForceRefresh><CorrectingLinks Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</CorrectingLinks><LinkCorrectTextFields Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</LinkCorrectTextFields><LinkCorrectionScope Type=\"Metalogix.SharePoint.Migration.LinkCorrectionScope\">SiteCollection</LinkCorrectionScope><UseComprehensiveLinkCorrection Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</UseComprehensiveLinkCorrection><AllowDBUserWriting Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</AllowDBUserWriting><MapGroupsByName Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</MapGroupsByName><OverwriteGroups Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</OverwriteGroups><MapMissingUsers Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</MapMissingUsers><MapMissingUsersToLoginName Type=\"System.String\" /><PersistMappings Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</PersistMappings><OverrideCheckouts Type=\"System.Boolean\">True</OverrideCheckouts><IsFromAdvancedMode Type=\"System.Nullable`1[[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]\" /><TelemetryLogs Type=\"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]\" /><EmailServer Type=\"System.String\" /><EmailUserName Type=\"System.String\" /><EmailPassword Type=\"System.String\" /><ToEmailAddress Type=\"System.String\" /><FromEmailAddress Type=\"System.String\" /><CCEmailAddress Type=\"System.String\" /><BCCEmailAddress Type=\"System.String\" /><EmailSuccessTemplateFilePath Type=\"System.String\" /><EmailFailureTemplateFilePath Type=\"System.String\" /><EmailSubject Type=\"System.String\" /><SendEmail Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</SendEmail><Transformers Type=\"Metalogix.Transformers.TransformerCollection\"><TransformerCollection /></Transformers><EnableSslForEmail Type=\"System.Boolean\">False</EnableSslForEmail></Action>");   

                    item.Update();
                }
            }
```

However it sets incorrect value as FalseFalse. How to save the correct value in multiple lines of text field

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will help you**

```
using (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite site = new Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://soweto:5000/sites/SPDWF_Issue"))
                {
                    using (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
               Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList list = web.Lists["Cust"];

                        Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();  

               SPFieldMultiLineText multilineField = item.Fields.GetField("YourColumn") as SPFieldMultiLineText;
               // Get the field value as HTML
               string htmltext= multilineField.GetFieldValueAsHtml(item["YourColumn"], item);

               //or Get the field as Text
               string normaltext= multilineField.GetFieldValueAsText(item["YourColumn"]); 

               //updating html field text
               htmltext+= "Hello I am being updated!";
               item["YourColumn"] = htmltext;
               item.Update();
             }
    }
```

Comment: This isn't working out. If instead of the given value I use some random value like "Demo" then it is working else not

Comment: As mentioned in the above code we are using text as "<Action ActionType .....>". So if this is used as the field value then on SHarePoint UI it is displayed as FalseFalseTrue.... And instead if we keep the text as just "Demo" then it is diplayed propeerly